# ASP.NET Core WEB API self-connection through external URL "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, multi-tenant, hangfire

I have multitenant Web API application with Hangfire scheduler that calls a task which trying to connect to self endpoint through external server DNS name with tenant name in it. Doing it this way, because Hangfire doesn't have HttpContext to resolve on which tenant task must shoot. On my staging server or if I send this request from Postman it works nice, but on my local machine and on production server it raises the error from title.

The code looks like nothing special:

```
var url = $"{tenant.Url}/notifications/client/send-appointment-sms";
var jwtToken = await _authService.GetTokenByUsername("admin");

using var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken.AccessToken);
var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

Where `tenant.Url` is for example https://api.tenant1.example.com/api2 which is available from browser on production server where application is running.

If I understanding clearly, my application can not connect to itself for some reason.
I have tried common solutions like firewall settings or disable proxy, still nothing on this point. What can I check next?

**UPD** I must add that NodeJS server on production is able to call this service too, so I think issue is not in server but maybe more about ASP.NET configuration settings.

Comment: If your application/runtime doesn't support concurrent requests then how can it respond to a new one generated by `SendAsync()` when it is executing a request? Sort of like a deadlock but with timeouts.

Comment: How did you determined that it doesn't support? Also, why is it working on staging enviroment? I think it's rather server network configuration issue.